# Как убрать коммиты от слова совсем?

Tags: git, github

Вот такая ситуация. Примерная история коммитов с комментариями.

1. Нормальный коммит, запушен на github
2. Нормальный коммит
3. Коммит, в который случайно попал новый файл на 200 мегабайт
4. Очередной коммит.
5. Коммит, в котором замечена неприятность, файл удален через git rm
6. Еще один коммит

Но теперь если пушить все это на github, то получается неприятность: большой файл там не принимается, и хотя его вроде бы и нет в коммите 5 и далее, но он есть в коммитах 3 и 4, и хотя он не нужен в принципе, пуш его все равно пытается залить.

Как корректно поступить в такой ситуации? Конечно, как вариант - откат к коммиту 2, и добавление все наново руками, что было в коммитах 3 и 4. Но не кажется хорошим решением. А как поступить лучше всего?

**Вот что делаю, по шагам.**

Создал тестовый репозиторий на github. Создал у себя репозиторий из одного файла `version` с цифрой 0 внутри.

0. Выполнил `Commit 0`.

Запустил прописанные на github

```
git remote add origin https://github.com/mikhajlo/Test.git
git branch -M main
git push -u origin main
```

1. Меняю цифру в `version` на 1, делаю `Commit 1` (`git commit -a` и `git push`).
2. Добавляю большой файл, меняю цифру в `version` на 2, делаю `Commit 2` (`git add large.rar` и `git commit -a`).
3. Меняю цифру в `version` на 3, делаю `Commit 3` (`git commit -a`).
4. Удаляю большой файл (`git rm -f large.rar`), меняю цифру в `version` на 4, делаю `Commit 4` (`git commit -a`).
5. Меняю цифру в `version` на 5, делаю `Commit 5` (`git commit -a`).

При попытке запушить получаю ошибку большого файла.

`git log` говорит

```
commit aecd9dd79cd79607b7440b013c72f3e02c7acbe6 (HEAD -> main)

    Commit 5

commit 874eb211adc6706f0626ff66db4d1092cdc3b72c

    Commit 4

commit a5c5801888b877962dfa6d6be18443723ea280a3

    Commit 3

commit 1813bf5e873ae3a7fc0ccb2f96cc7b0547f7b759

    Commit 2

commit c776ffc36977b52f8e497e90f03c9591b98c6ac3 (origin/main)

    Commit 1

commit 0fa879ac87277db8def7a43ea10323627f9ceb46

    Commit 0
```

Вот теперь тот же вопрос, что и раньше, только, пожалуйста, со всеми командами от и до, чтоб не было никаких разночтений и непоняток...

P.S. Просьба не гнать читать учебники — Pro Git от Scott Chacon & Ben Straub прочел. Очень уж запутанно и непонятно... Если можете предложить что-то понятное (реально понятное, а не как в этой книжке...) и на русском (чтоб не мучиться сначала с переводом, потом с пониманием) - буду признателен.

P.P.S. Более непонятной системы с более непонятной идеологией и документацией не встречал, разве что Linux...

Comment: в начале коммиты идут с индексом от 1, а потом - от 0. Это сбивает с толку

Comment: Чем не устраивает вариант с soft reset + откоммитить все заново? Если всего 6 коммитов, я бы так и сделал, куда меньше шансов напортачить, чем с rebase.

Comment: @MSDN.WhiteKnight Я не понимаю, что вы имеете в виду, но в реальной ситуации я просто снес все к черту, сохранив исходники, снял с github'а последний имеющийся там коммит, перекопировал сохраненные исходники поверх снятых с github'а и закоммитил. Да, потерял промежуточные коммиты, зато просто и понятно, что происходит. И вообще, уже в привычку вошло на всякий случай весь каталог перед очередными коммитами просто копировать - тогда какая бы гадость ни случилась, есть откуда восстановить... Понимаете, для меня все эти rebase или reset практически неразличимы. Я реально никак не могу поняит идею.

Comment: [git reset](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-reset) с ключом --soft позволяет удалить коммиты до определенной точки в истории, но не трогает текущее состояние файлов. После этого изменения можно откоммитить заново. reset безопаснее, чем rebase, можно просто в git GUI найти в истории нужный коммит, правой кнопкой и выбрать reset. Изменения появятся в ожидающих коммита, можно будет создать коммиты в новой последовательности.

Comment: @MSDN.WhiteKnight Ну хорошо... удалить коммиты. Но что это означает? Что все файлы, созданные в промежуточных коммитах, тоже будут удалены? Не из **текущего проекта**, из самой базы данных? Как будто они туда никогда и не добавлялись? Или будет, как после действий по совету user7860670, когда просто появляется новая ветвь, и теперь вместо одного пути с ошибкой их просто становится два, один верный, другой нет, и все равно все это надо заливать на github, да еще и как-то "сливать"? Где найти **нормальное** описание того, что происходит при всех этих 1001 ключике?... :(

Comment: Удалить - это значить их не будет в истории коммитов. Не уверен, будут ли все файлы окончательно удалены из индекса, возможно, понадобиться еще [git gc](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-gc) чтобы удалить неиспользуемые объекты. Никакой второй ветки точно не создается.

Comment: "Где найти нормальное описание того, что происходит при всех этих 1001 ключике?." - по ссылке и есть нормальное описание. Если по нему непонятно, лучше всего создать небольшой репозиторий с парой файлов и попробовать на практике.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Переделываете историю, избавляясь от коммитов, относящихся к проблемным файлам

```
git rebase --onto <последний нормальный коммит> <коммит, в который случайно попал новый файл> <oчередной коммит>
```

Затем устанавливаете ветку на новый oчередной коммит и пушите. Коммит 1813bf5e873ae3a7fc0ccb2f96cc7b0547f7b759 будет выпилен полностью.

```
git checkout c776ffc36977b52f8e497e90f03c9591b98c6ac3 
git rebase --onto c776ffc36977b52f8e497e90f03c9591b98c6ac3 1813bf5e873ae3a7fc0ccb2f96cc7b0547f7b759 874eb211adc6706f0626ff66db4d1092cdc3b72c
(возможно тут попросит разрулить правку version 2 / 3)
git branch -f main
git push origin main
```

Если <Коммит, в который случайно попал новый файл> нужно сохранить без этого файла, то cначала переключаетесь на этот коммит, удаляете файл и делаете изменения `git commit --amend`, а потом перенос уже с этим отредактированным коммитом. Модифицированный коммит 1813bf5e873ae3a7fc0ccb2f96cc7b0547f7b759 останется, но без большого файла.

```
git checkout 1813bf5e873ae3a7fc0ccb2f96cc7b0547f7b759
git rm large.rar
git commit --amend
(Закрываете редактор комментария коммита без правок. Получаете новый коммит 2-alt.)
git rebase --onto 2-alt-id 1813bf5e873ae3a7fc0ccb2f96cc7b0547f7b759 874eb211adc6706f0626ff66db4d1092cdc3b72c
git branch -f main
git push origin main
```

Comment: Каюсь, я снес у себя все и создал репозиторий заново. Сейчас заново восстановил похожую ситуацию. Не пойму, что значит "устанавливаете ветку на новый oчередной коммит и пушите". У меня ветки разошлись в стороны, появился новый коммит с тем же комментарием... Словом, я чуть позже создам точный тестовый пример в вопрос, потому что что-то это все запутало только куда сильнее...

Comment: @Mikhailo именно это и означает. Ветка - это указатель на коммит, его можно переставить на любой который вам нужен. Из командной строки это делается через `git reset` или `git checkout -b`

Comment: Я дополнил свой вопрос. Не могли бы вы подправить свой ответ всеми командами - полными, с указаниями коммитов - ну, чтоб можно было скопировать их в командную строку и выполнить? Словесное объяснение меня вгоняет в полный ступор, честно говоря. Проще все с нуля создать, чем в этом "богатстве" разобраться...

Comment: Смотрим только на то, что во второй части. В идеале, конечно, хотелось бы иметь коммиты 2,3,4, но без большого файла. Но я понимаю, что скорее всего хочу невозможного, так что устраивает такая окончательная последовательность коммитов - 0,1,5. Выбросить 2,3 и 4, как если бы их никогда не было. Еще, как вариант - сделать так, чтоб они были на локальном диске, но не на github'е. Но это тоже, как мне кажется, невозможно.

Comment: @Mikhailo Расписал подробнее. По факту тут просто id коммитов нужные подствить

Comment: Сделал. Опять не то выходит. Теперь у меня все заканчивается тем, что есть коммиты 0,1, измененный 2, а коммитов 3,4,5 — тю-тю... И (для меня) совершенно непонятно теперь, что это вышло - `commit 3e50f08fdd41877e07913135ac34603fe08048a3 (HEAD, origin/main, origin/HEAD, main)` — тут тебе и `HEAD`, и `main`, и... вконец запутался. Это что - четыре ветви или куда?

Comment: И на каком шаге они пропали? Да, это четыре ветви. У вас и раньше столько должно было быть. Хотя HEAD это чисто служебное

Comment: Ну не знаю. Делал все, как вы сказали. Теперь `git log` выводит 3 коммита. Ощущение, что пропали соразу, после `checkout`,но я ж не думал, что надо все это проверять... Ладно, хрен с ним, понял, что ничего уже не получится... буду надеяться, что в следующий раз такую ерунду не сделаю, и все будет OK. Ну и в крайнем случае всегда есть бэкап целым каталогом :) У меня так уже лет 5-6 бекап системного диска живет - просто образ диска раз в неделю, и два последних хранятся. Не раз спасало. Как и бекап рабочего каталога.

Comment: `git log` выводит коммиты текущей ветки, сразу после checkout оно действительно должно показывать коммиты до того, на который указывает HEAD. Используйте `git log --all --graph`

Comment: Все то же самое, только со звездочками :) Три коммита.

Comment: Не может быть. После `checkout` вытка `main` и все из origin должны продолжать указывать на прежние позиции. По сути  `checkout` только переносит указатель текущей ветки ниже

Comment: Я теперь не знаю, как на github'е вернуть назад. Придется создавать новый репозиторий... Давайте так: что именно я должен проверять, какой командой, чтоб вы поверили? Какие данные вам выслать?

Comment: Я верю в то, что могу воспроизвести у себя. А назад все вернуть по идее можно весьма легко, достаточно сделать `git checkout aecd9dd79cd79607b7440b013c72f3e02c7acbe6` и поставить все ветки на начальные позиции По идее, локальный репозиторий еще не должен был очиститься от мусора, если только вы не используйте какой-нибудь трешовый git клиент

Comment: Ну так вы же об этом не написали! После git checkout да, появился пятый, но теперь у меня две расходящиеся ветви. Одна - 0-1-2(старый)-3-4-5. Вторая 0-1-2(новый). И как мне их теперь собрать в одну?

Comment: *"Ну так вы же об этом не написали!"* - о чем не написал? Это как раз и делает команда `git rebase --onto`

Comment: Ну я же ее уже один раз делал. Теперь-то что во что? Ну вот какой чудак на очень большую букву М придумал этот git...

Comment: Да, git из комплекта Visual Studio 2022.

Comment: если бы вы ее сделали, то получилась бы последовательность 0-1- и далее новые коммиты, заканчивая 5

Comment: *"Ну вот какой чудак на очень большую букву М придумал этот git..."* - Линус Торвальдс. Только он не придумал, он взял систему Монохром и выпилил оттуда контроль целостности, транзакционность, и т.п. и заменил локальную бд файликами.

Comment: Ладно, всё. Может, когда-нибудь вернусь, если опять захочется попытаться понять. Но пока - гори он синим пламенем, с моей точки зрения более непонятный софт написать трудно. Кстати, судя по объему базы - так проще хранить набор копий каталогов. По карйней мере куда проще...

Comment: Про Линуса не удивили. После операционки, которой невозможно пользоваться, следовало ждать систему контроля версий с той же характеристикой...

Comment: Кстати да да, гит же по умолчанию для каждого коммита добавляет в хранилище измененные файлы целиком, а не только разницу. А для компактификации этого хранилища есть специальный набор команд еще...

Answer (score 4):

Более простой (ну, как посмотреть) вариант:

```
git rebase -i origin/main
```

Эта команда сформирует файл со списком коммитов и откроет его в текстовом редакторе по умолчанию (осторожно, это может оказаться vi если вы его не настраивали).

Дальше надо найти строчку с 5м коммитом, изменить в ней команду pick на fixup и переставить её сразу после третьего. После чего файл нужно сохранить и выйти из редактора.

---

Еще более простой вариант доступен если вы ещё не успели сделать 5й коммит. В таком случае его можно сделать используя ключ `--fixup`, после чего применить rebase в режиме autosquash:

```
git commit --fixup 1813bf5e873ae3a7fc0ccb2f96cc7b0547f7b759
git rebase -i --autosquash origin/main
```

В таком случае git rebase вам откроет список комитов упорядоченных сразу как надо, вам останется только убедиться что всё правильно и выйти из текстового редактора.

---

PS Не игнорируйте существование GUI. Нормальные инструменты позволяют сделать всё что я написал выше без заучивания команд и копания в манах. Нормальным GUI под винду если что является Git Extensions, под линукс вроде бы тоже что-то было.

Comment: *Не игнорируйте существование GUI*  Ну, я вовсю копался в gitk, но ничего, что помогло бы мне, найти не смог.

Comment: @Mikhailo ищите клиенты которые могут делать вот так: [раз](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fxjnS.png), [два](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j69GW.png)

Comment: Сделал тестовый репозиторий, воспроизвел, как мог... Запустил rebase для последнего коммита. Все, что получил в редакторе — одну строку: `noop`. Ну, и с комментарием большой список команд. Писать команды вручную? Честно говоря, понять, какие и как... Я понимаю, что, возможно, я просто дурак, но более запутанный и недружелюбный к пользователю, чем git - разве что только Linux :) Наличие 20 команд на любой чих, и каждая с 20 ключиками мешает понять сам принцип. Сразу: да, книги читал. Тот же Pro Git от Scott Chacon & Ben Straub. Очень запутанно и непонятно...

Comment: @Mikhailo а зачем вы запускали для последнего-то коммита? Я же писал: для последнего *нормального*, т.е. вы делаете rebase указывая тот коммит который менять не нужно. Те коммиты, которые находятся между текущим и указанным, будут переписаны.

Comment: @Mikhailo если что, "нормальность" коммита - это ваша собственная терминология из вопроса

Comment: Нормальный - это какой? 1, 2, 3, 4, 5? Я же их специально пронумеровал, чтоб не было разночтений. Я же при вашем варианте потеряю все, что было в коммите 4. Мне надо, чтоб был коммит 5, но чтоб файба большого не было вообще. Давайте я добавил коммит 6, чтоб было понятнее. Мне нужно запушить коммит 6 так, чтоб о коммитах 3-4-5 просто забыть вообще. Выбросить их. Как если бы после коммита 2 шел сразу коммит 6.

Comment: @Mikhailo "Нормальный" - это тот про который вы именно так и написали: "нормальный". То есть 1й и 2й. Последний нормальный - это 2й.

Comment: *"Я же при вашем варианте потеряю все, что было в коммите 4"* - с фига ли вы его потеряете-то? Если вы внимательно сделаете то что я написал, то у вас будут склеенные коммиты 3 и 5, а после них 4й.

Comment: С коммитом 6 стало ещё мене понятно. Так вам надо сохранить 4й или нет? Вы уж определитесь.

Comment: Вот, дополненный вопрос. Смотрим только на то, что во второй части. В идеале, конечно, хотелось бы иметь коммиты 2,3,4, но без большого файла. Но я понимаю, что хочу невозможного, так что устраивает такая последовательность коммитов - 0,1,5. Выбросить 2,3 и 4, как если бы их никогда не было. Еще, как вариант - сделать так, чтоб они были на локальном диске, но не на github'е. Но это тоже, как я понимаю, невозможно.

Comment: @Mikhailo а давайте вы всё-таки не будете менять хотелки на ходу, и сосредоточитесь на решении исходного вопроса - выбрасывания одного файла из коммита?

Comment: @Mikhailo всё что вам нужно - это выполнить одну (!) команду указав ей правильные параметры. Почему вы вместо того чтобы указать эти параметры занимаетесь написанием комментариев о том что это, видите ли, невозможно?

Comment: В принципе любой вопрос решается, что называется, "одной командой". Только вот какой и с какими параметрами - из документации совершенно непонятно. Как и то, что git может, а что нет. Так что я для себя просто методом тыка нашел 2-3 команды, которых мне хватает. Только и всего. Как по мне, все эти ветви и т.п. — просто unix-стиль, когда пишут не для того, чтобы пользоваться, а чтобы показать всю свою крутизну — а я могу еще и игру сюда встроить, и спелл-чекер, и браузер!...

Comment: @Mikhailo я вам эту команду привёл. В чём сложность её написать и причём тут вообще unix стиль?

Comment: @Mikhailo она либо работает либо нет, если не работает - напишите что именно она не так делает. Зачем мне знать какими командами вы пользуетесь и про чужую крутизну?