# Как удалить старый, конкретный коммит из истории (github в том числе)?

Tags: git, github

В файл случайно вписал токены бота, закоммитил и запушил, забыл стереть или заменить.

Вспомнил только через несколько коммитов вперёд и теперь стоит задача удалить старые коммиты из истории.

В новых коммитах токены удалены, но если зайти в старый коммит и посмотреть историю изменений, то там имеются строчки с теми самыми токенами, которые показывать не нужно.

Есть ли способ полностью удалить коммит из истории?

Для наглядности:

**v.0.1** - токенов нет

**v.1.0** - токены есть

**v1.1** - токены удалил

**v1.2** - . . .

**v2.0** - . . .

Необходимо удалить из истории **v.1.0**, ибо там хранятся токены, затем удалить **v.1.1**, так как там пишутся изменения между этим и предыдущим комитом, соответственно токены светятся снова.

Откатываться назад, удаляя все последующие коммиты и вписывать изменения вручную не вариант. [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как убрать коммиты от слова совсем?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1531915/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%83%d0%b1%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%bc%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8b-%d0%be%d1%82-%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0-%d1%81%d0%be%d0%b2%d1%81%d0%b5%d0%bc)

Comment: После git rebase -i origin/master в файле есть только noop и дальше комментарии.

Comment: А смысл? Всё рано надо токены отзывать, раз они утекли.

Comment: Это понятно, скорее как пример именно с токенами. Что если там будут какие-нибудь данные, которые нельзя изменить или фича, которую необходимо как можно быстрые скрыть от лишних глаз. Суть та же, не важно какие именно данные были в коммите, вопрос в том, как его удалить полностью из истории.

Comment: Не надо делать `git rebase -i`...

Comment: Прочитал Ваш ответ на тот вопрос, попробовал совершить всё в своих условиях, но как-то безрезультатно. Звучит не очень конкретно, но чтобы дать больше конкретики, необходимо понимать, что делаешь детально. Я не самый продвинутый пользователь git, мягко говоря, поэтому пояснить в чём причина не могу.