# Удалить отдельно взятый коммит

Tags: git, git-commit

И так есть очередь из пяти коммитов 1 2 3 4 5. нужно удалить 3 коммит таким образом чтобы остальные остались. то есть чтобы было так. 1 2 4 5. как это сделать?

Comment: Читайте про interactive rebase (и потом force push). Учитывайте, что коммиты 4 и 5 будут пересозданы с другими хешами, без этого никак.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как убрать коммиты от слова совсем?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1531915/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%83%d0%b1%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%bc%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8b-%d0%be%d1%82-%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0-%d1%81%d0%be%d0%b2%d1%81%d0%b5%d0%bc)